# Promisification by using resolve or reject or with Promisify (bluebird)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Hi I have a method in which I use the Promise class provided by bluebird to either resolve or reject based on the result of a third party function. My concern is that the third party function is synchronous and hence could throw an error. Below is my code:

```js
Authenticator.prototype.createJWTResponse = function(user, secret) {
  if (user && user.ID) {
    var expires = moment().add(7, 'days').valueOf();
    //encode is third party and synchronous that can throw error
    var token = jwt.encode({
      iss: user.ID,
      exp: expires
    }, secret);

    //throw new Error("thrown by a promise method");

    return Promise.resolve({
      token: token,
      expires: expires,
      user: {}
    });

  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Authenticator:createJWTResponse: user object missing or doesnt have ID'));
  }
};
```

One option is that I do not use reject and response in the method and make it a normal callback method which is then promisified by Promise.promisify. However my question is; if there is a way to use resolve and reject and create a promise in case the third party method throws an exception.
Another question that I have is; it is not stated in bluebird documentation; that if one is using resolve and reject in a method; can such a method be promisified?
I tried to promisify the above method but it fails to return for some reason & doesnt throw an error; which makes me suspect that if one is using resolve, reject in a method then such a method cannot be promisifed.

Can someone clarify this for me? Thanks in advance.

(Update)

If I wrap the method in Promise.method; bluebird throws a very clear error as follows:

Possibly unhandled Error: Synchronous Error in otherwise promise returning method

Returning a Promise.try from inside this method also throws the same error as in case of Promise.method.

Wrapping the code in the method in a try catch and rejecting on error also throws:

Possibly unhandled Error:

(Solution)

As suggested by Benjamin; taking away all resolve and reject calls from within the method and wrapping it in Promise.method gives the expected result. The final code is as follows:

```js
Authenticator.prototype.createJWTResponse = Promise.method(function(user, secret) {
  if (user && user.ID) {
    var expires = moment().add(7, 'days').valueOf();
    var token = jwt.encode({
      iss: user.ID,
      exp: expires
    }, secret);

    //Note: This is caught by the catch block on this method
    //throw new Error('sync error thrown');

    return {
      token: token,
      expires: expires,
      user: {}
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('Authenticator:createJWTResponse: user object missing or doesnt have id');
  }
});
```

Even a callback in not required in this case.

Comment: why dont you just put the third party method in a try/catch block and return a rejected promise in case of an error

Comment: @johndoe90 that  seems like the most logical way to get the code working without using promisify on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all .promisify already converts throws to rejections.

As for normal promisification - the promise constructor is throw safe, you can use `Promise.method` which is throw safe.

The reason sync throws are converted to rejects is in order to create a consistent API and so you won't have to .catch and catch all the time.

Comment: `.promisify` only works correctly on functions that expect a callback, which is why it isn't working out here.

Comment: If a function already returns a promise then there is no need to promisify it, on the other hand if a function is synchronous then there is no need to promisify it

Comment: Aaron I originally had this method accepting a callback which was working fine. However my logic is to try to be consistent and use promises in the first place so that I don't have to promisify every metho.

Comment: @Nosh if you just want to convert return values/throws to returned resolves/rejections simply use `Promise.method`